# Обучение SOM на таблице Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

Хотелось бы спросить, можно ли обучить данную сеть на данных из файла Excel.[image: Файл с предоставленными данными]

При изучении принципов работы карт Кохонена, мне не удалось понять как использовать данные в виде многомерных векторов. И также мне хотелось бы узнать как можно реализовать данную задачу с помощью Python.

В качестве базы данных используется файл Excel на 711 строк с данными в виде действительных чисел, в столбцах указанны группы на которые эти данные разделяются.

Насколько я понял, для работы с такого рода файлами используется библиотека Pandas, но как именно мне следует преобразовать файл, мне не довелось понять.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SOMNetwork():
    def __init__(self, input_dim, dim=10, sigma=None, learning_rate=0.1, 
tay2=1000, dtype=tf.float32):
    if not sigma:
        sigma = dim / 2
    self.dtype = dtype
    self.dim = tf.constant(dim, dtype=tf.int64)
    self.learning_rate = tf.constant(learning_rate, dtype=dtype, name='learning_rate')
    self.sigma = tf.constant(sigma, dtype=dtype, name='sigma')
    self.tay1 = tf.constant(1000/np.log(sigma), dtype=dtype, name='tay1')
    self.minsigma = tf.constant(sigma * np.exp(-1000/(1000/np.log(sigma))), dtype=dtype, name='min_sigma')
    self.tay2 = tf.constant(tay2, dtype=dtype, name='tay2')
    #input vector
    self.x = tf.placeholder(shape=[input_dim], dtype=dtype, name='input')
    #iteration number
    self.n = tf.placeholder(dtype=dtype, name='iteration')
    #variables
    self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([dim*dim, input_dim], minval=-1, maxval=1, dtype=dtype),
        dtype=dtype, name='weights')
    #helper
    self.positions = tf.where(tf.fill([dim, dim], True))

def feed(self, input):
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init.run()
        win_index = sess.run(self.__competition(), feed_dict={self.x: input})
        win_index_2d = np.array([win_index//self.dim.eval(), win_index-win_index//self.dim.eval()*self.dim.eval()])
    return win_index_2d


def training_op(self):
    win_index = self.__competition('train_')
    with tf.name_scope('cooperation') as scope:
        coop_dist = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.cast(self.positions -
            [win_index//self.dim, win_index-win_index//self.dim*self.dim], 
            dtype=self.dtype)), axis=1))
        sigma = tf.cond(self.n > 1000, lambda: self.minsigma, lambda: self.sigma * tf.exp(-self.n/self.tay1))
        sigma_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Sigma', sigma)
        tnh = tf.exp(-tf.square(coop_dist) / (2 * tf.square(sigma))) # topological neighbourhood
    with tf.name_scope('adaptation') as scope:
        lr = self.learning_rate * tf.exp(-self.n/self.tay2)
        minlr = tf.constant(0.01, dtype=self.dtype, name='min_learning_rate')
        lr = tf.cond(lr <= minlr, lambda: minlr, lambda: lr)
        lr_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Learning rate', lr)
        delta = tf.transpose(lr * tnh * tf.transpose(self.x - self.w))
        training_op = tf.assign(self.w, self.w + delta)
    return training_op, lr_summary, sigma_summary

def __competition(self, info=''):
    with tf.name_scope(info+'competition') as scope:
        distance = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(self.x - self.w), axis=1))
    return tf.argmin(distance, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Pandas это делается очень просто:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Pandas сам распознает типы данных (кроме дат и времени - их надо указывать явно).

Чтобы преобразовать DataFrame в Numpy 2D Array:

```
arr = df.values
```

Фактически Pandas.DataFrame это коллекция `1D Numpy arrays` (столбцов).

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что мне следует преобразовать каждый столбец в массив? И, понимаю, что глупый вопрос, но как использовать полученный массивы для обучения и тестирования сети? Для последующего тестирования будут использоваться случайные числа из другой базы. И также хотелось поинтересоваться о наличии ошибок в написании сети.

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл обратиться.

Comment: @WindWolf, я так понимаю вопрос был в том как прочитать Excel в Pandas... Как его "скормить" в вашу TensorFlow модель я не знаю... Вы этот код сами писали?

Comment: К сожалению, нет... Это часть совместного проекта в котором от участвовал человек, который должен был объяснить как этим пользоваться, однако он не проявляет желания продолжать участие в проекте. Ситуация довольно странная и сроки сдачи близятся, а я не совсем понимаю то как мне его доделать. В итоге я решил спросить тут.

Comment: @WindWolf, здесь принято задавать один вопрос (в одном StackOverflow вопросе)  и вопрос этот обычно о том, что у вас конкретно не получается. В вашем случае, вам, по-моему, надо найти фрилансера или ментора, который вам объяснит как работает (должен работать) данный код...

Comment: В любом случае, благодарю за ответы. Просто поиски были тщетными и решил попробовать. Однако впредь буду использовать данный сервис, как принято.